# R programming : How to remove Duplicates in a column based on values of another column

Tags: r

```
A   B
15  O
20  O
12  C
15  C
50  C
25  O
50  O
19  O
50  M
```

I have a data of the above format.
I want to select unique rows based on unique elements in column A
But incase there are duplicates then I need to refer to column B and select the one which has code 'C'

Expected Output:

```
A   B
20  O
12  C
15  C
50  C
25  O
19  O
```

Can anyone help..

Comment: It is better to have data showed like above (or even better is `dput`), but an image is a not recommended as others cannot copy it from the image.  I rolled back to previous edit

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'A', `order` based on the logical condition (`B==O`), and get the first row with `head`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(B=="O"), head(.SD, 1), A]
#    A B
#1: 12 C
#2: 15 C
#3: 50 C
#4: 20 O
#5: 25 O
#6: 19 O
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R` by `order`ing and get the `unique` elements with `duplicated`

```
df2 <- df1[order(df1$A, df1$B=="O"),]
df2[!duplicated(df2$A),]
```